# Which credentials are used when browsing a directory through IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis, iis-7

We have an IIS site with an application.

The application points to a physical path on the C drive.

In the "Connect As" settings "Application user (pass-through authentication)" is selected.

The user that I am logged in as has full control of the directory and no problem viewing the directory in windows explorer.

When I try to browse I get a 401 error, if I give "Everyone" access to the directory it works fine.

How do I get IIS to use my credentials, or some configured credentials to browse the directory?

Comment: Do you have Windows authentication enabled? If you use Anonymous Authentication your Windows users are not passed through and the Application Pool identity is used to access the directory.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it is the Network Service account.  Check the account the app pool is configured with.  You can also create a new App Pool and configure it to use any account on the local system.  Finally you'll want to allow that account to have read permissions on the folder with the files.